# Code Coverage for C++ dlls through Ruby which uses WIN32OLE

Tags: c++, ruby, code-coverage

I'm running into a particular issue when I wanted to implement the code coverage for our project. Our project is being developed using C++ and the output is libraries (dlls).

We, the testers write RUBY which uses WIN32OLE to register the dlls and test the functions in the libraries.

Now we wanted to implement Code Coverage for our project. But we do not want to spend time in writing Unit tests for C++ to see the code coverage since we have already implemented testing in Ruby.

So is there any tool or any way to analyze the code coverage of the DLLs through Ruby?

Thanks, 
Vimal

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can get code coverage for your C/C++ DLLs using [C++ Coverage Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-coverage.php).

**Using the GUI**

On the launch dialog put the path to the ruby interpreter as the program you want to launch (**d:\ruby\ruby.exe**). Then put the name of your ruby script as in the arguments field (**test1.rb**) and put the starting directory in the startup directory field (**d:\tests\test1**).

Then start the program with the Go or Start Application button. Your ruby program will be executed. When the DLLs are loaded C++ Coverage Validator identify the DLLs with debug information (PDB, COFF, Stabs, CodeView, etc) and perform code coverage for them.

**Using the command line**

You can also do this from the command line:

**coverageValidator.exe -program d:\ruby\ruby.exe -arg test1.rb -directory d:\tests\test1**

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I've already tried with C++ Coverage Validator. But it seems they are not supporting 64-bit.

Our project is built using Win32 platform and runs in 64-bit machine also.

Comment: Vimal, you are mistaken. There is a 64 bit C++ Coverage Validator. You get to it by clicking the Beta button (right next to the Eval) button on the C++ Coverage Validator page. It's fully functional (and was there when you checked the page on Oct 2012 - you just missed it or didn't want to join the beta).